# LED Driver Using Boost Converter, startup problem

Tags: led, boost, led-driver

**I am trying to drive a led using a DC-DC boost converter.**
The circuit worked at first, I ran the led for 2-3 hours without issue (a few days ago).

**Today** I flipped the switch to turn the led on and right **when it turned on** the light started flickering and **smoke came from the boost converter**. After closer inspection one of the mosfets had burned (see image): 
[image: boost converter]
[image: boost converter closeup]
The Boost converter is rated for 250Watt 10A (link: https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/32793038906.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dDRHkKW).

**The led (100W , 30-34v, 3A forward current) is current limited** (using one of the pots on the boost converter) **to just under 3A** and the led is **running at approx 32v at this Amperage.**
Therefore, **P≈96Watt** which the converter should easily handle.

***link to LED:***https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/32831596858.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4do24sCZ
**I have the 'white' version**

I've read about **'LED inrush current'** and think this might have caused the booster board to fail. Could this be the reason for the board failing or is it likely to have another cause?

If the issue is the inrush current how could i prevent/lower the current spike when turning on the led? would it help to start the led at a lower voltage using PWM (paired with arduino in my case) and increase the voltage slowly up to 32volt  to potentially lower the current spike/prevent the board from failing? Does anyone know how conventional LED drivers get around this problem?

**Shematic of my circuit:**
[image]

**I am using a PWM IC to dim the led, here's a link to it:** https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/32665973238.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dUxGjE5

If I am doing something wrong please tell me. Any input will be greatly appreciated. **Thank you very much!**

Comment: I'd assume your LEDs were relatively innocuous. And I've personally experienced poor converter designs from suppliers in China, where the output needed a predictable load at all times or it would self-destruct. (Some worked, some didn't, but I found the only secure way to power them up was to make certain they had an output capacitor as well as an output resistor at all times. Then they "just worked.") It may not be entirely your fault.

Comment: @jonk thank you for this info! Could you please tell me what the approximate value of the output capacitor/resistor should be or how i should determine these values.
I am quite the novice...

Comment: Set the resistor to use about 5-10% of the expected LED load current. The capacitor? I can't really say. But I used something on the order of \$47\:\mu\text{F}\$. I think the resistor is more important. But both worked fine for me.

Comment: I'd GUESS that the current limit did not function rapidly enough on startup - a subset of what Jonk says. | Does/did the failure occur with PWM set to low? Adding a slow start to the PWM board (possibly as simple as a largish capacitor from a pot wiper to ground (possibly) may cause the dimmer to start at 0% while the buck regulator "finds its feet".  Using a small fixed load 'upstream' of the PWM MAY also be useful based on what Jonk says.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I just checked, it looks like the Pot was set to just over minimum (minimum=approx 10% duty cycle)

Comment: Maybe a cap on the boost converter to make it start at Vmin and ramp up.  || Is the IC identifiable?

Comment: Ic is non identifiable. I'll ask the sellee for the part number..

Comment: @ RussellMcMahon The IC is NCE6075K According to the seller